# How to declare foward a template of template (of a class)

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

Sorry I'm new to templates and I searched a lot, but I can't find a solution how to declare forward a template of template (of a class).

Here my code:

```
#ifndef CMAP_H
#define CMAP_H

#include "qvector.h"

class CMap
{
public:
    CMap(const unsigned int & width, const unsigned int & height, const unsigned int & hexagonRadius);
    CMap(const unsigned int & width, const unsigned int & height, const unsigned int & hexagonRadius, const QVector<QVector<unsigned int> > & landType);
    ~CMap();
private:
    class Pimple;
    Pimple * d;
};

#endif // CMAP_H
```

All I want is to make the #include "qvector.h" obsolent.

Comment: Why do you not want to include the appropriate header?

Comment: @James Because he wants to limit the amount of files being recompiles when qvector.h changes. It's a noble goal.

Comment: @quant_dev:  Based on the OP's previous posts, `QVector<T>` is from Qt; if so, it isn't changing all that frequently.

Comment: All right, I thought that it's his local header file, as he includes it with quotes.

Comment: oh sorry for quotes it. Did I understand it right, that it only make sense to make the includes obsolent when include a selfmade header file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do

```
template <typename T>  class QVector;
```

See [on codepad](http://codepad.org/uYy1nC10):

```
#ifndef CMAP_H
#define CMAP_H

template <typename T>  class QVector;

class CMap
{
public:
    CMap(const unsigned int & width, const unsigned int & height, const unsigned int & hexagonRadius);
    CMap(const unsigned int & width, const unsigned int & height, const unsigned int & hexagonRadius, const QVector<QVector<unsigned int> > & landType);
    ~CMap();
private:
    class Pimple;
    Pimple * d;
};

#endif // CMAP_H
```